# How can i set a name or custom attribute for a specific storeview through REST API?

Tags: magento2, store-view, rest-api, custom-attributes

How can i set a name or custom attribute for a specific storeview through REST API?

Adding a product hroug POST /V1/products it seems like it only  sets the Name/Label for the default storeview and in other storeview Name and custom attribute are set to use default value.

Is there a way to add or update the other storeviews name and custom attribute values

/Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured it out myself. Just include the storeview code before V1

In my case i would perform a PUT on www.mystorehost.com/rest/default_en/V1/products{sku}

/Thomas